# SQLAlchemy cast result of to_timestamp function to date

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using Postgres and SQLAlchemy as the ORM.

I have this query and I cannot seem to convert it to SQLAlchemy.

```sql
select to_timestamp(create_time)::date from inventory_item
```

create_time column is epoch time. The result of this query is this:

```
2019-02-24
```

Here's what I tried so far

`InventoryItem.query.with_entities(db.func.to_timestamp(InventoryItem.create_time)).filter_by(inventory_id="1810092340894EA").first()`

Result from this query is this.

`(datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 9, 23, 40, 17, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=480, name=None)),)`

I only want the date and exclude the time.

I tried the tagged duplicate answer, but it is not working.

`InventoryItem.query.with_entities(cast(InventoryItem.create_time, Date)).filter_by(order_id="1810092340894EA").first()`

Result:

`sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) cannot cast type integer to date`

Comment: @bhargavrao where did all the comments go?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, deleted by the comment posters. I deleted the 3 comments that were updated into the question. Given that the poster informed later that the dupe solved their issue, I did not py-hammer reopen.